# Is there (or was there ever) a way to change the value of the "true" keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Someone told me he once had a bug that somehow caused the `true` keyword to be assigned to `false` and from then on a code such as `if (true) {...}` would not run.

Can this happen in javascript somehow?

Perhaps in its earlier days?

Comment: Explicitly must have been set to false somewhere..

Comment: Did that someone have it in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, the story was about js specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `true` cannot be assigned a new value.

Doing

```
true = false;
```

would give

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Also, as per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-names-and-keywords)

> The syntactic grammar defines Identifier as an IdentifierName that is
>   not a ReservedWord

so you can still have `window.true = false;` which is essentially `window["true"] = false` or `window[true] = false`.

Also the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words) says

> A reserved word is an IdentifierName that cannot be used as an
>   Identifier.
>
> Syntax
>
> > ReservedWord ::
> >     Keyword
> >     FutureReservedWord
> >     NullLiteral
> >     **BooleanLiteral**

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I also tried to set `windows.true = false`, but when evaluating `true`, JS still prefers the built-in `true` over the property of the global object. However, I can imagine that there was some old version, or maybe a specific implementation, where either of these experiments would yield other results.

Comment: @GolezTrol No, since as per spec http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-names-and-keywords reserved words cannot be identifier name, it doesn't stop them from being a property name though, `window.true` is equivalent to `window["true"]`

Comment: @JamesThorpe, Yes, It took me a while to get that point..And Gloez is right, parser must have some different glasses to read _Reserved Words_

Comment: @gurvinder372, `window["true"]` is fine but as other global variables, if we set `window.true=false` and then type `true` in console, it does not return `window` value of `true` property but returns `true`..

Comment: @RayonDabre That is because as per the spec http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-names-and-keywords reserved words cannot be identifier name but can be a property name `"true"` is not same as `true`

Comment: @gurvinder372, It would be interesting to investigate how JS engine differentiate them..

Comment: @RayonDabre any ideas where I could find JS engine execution semantics?

Answer (score 1):

Well, This is completely not possible in JavaScript.

We can do it in some other languages such as, overload true and false to return a specific value.

So, true will return false and false will return true.

```
public static bool operator true() {    
      return false; 
  }
```

Comment: Also possible in python: `True = False`